# ASP.NET Identity WebApi 2 vs MVC 5 Sign In Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and WebApi 2 and trying to do an Ajax login with redirect if successfull.

For authentication I am using the ASP.NET Identity libraries that come by default for a new ASP.NET MVC project.

I got everything working and all was fine using MVC 5. But for the life of me, I cannot get the standard MVC controller to return just simple JSON. (It wraps my JSON I want to return in a parent object) yes i could fix this on the client side, but that to me is hacky.

My other option which seems better, is to use WebApi which returns objects as I expect them (just my JSON as the body). But the problem I am having is that ASP.NET Identity `SignInManager` is not sending the `.ASPNet.Identity` cookies, unless I return an ActionResult.

The below is my WebApi controller, which is returning correct expected minimal JSON but is not sending Set-Cookie commands, therefore any redirect sees the user as not logged in.

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    public AccountController(IApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public IApplicationSignInManager SignInManager {....}

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [NgValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        // Temporarily using Dynamic 
        dynamic res = new ExpandoObject();

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var status = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        res.status = status.ToString();

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res))
        };
    }
}
```

which returns the following Json but no cookies:

```
{"status":"Success"}
```

If i change this to return an ActionResult rather than HttpResponseMessage, the Set-Cookie commands are being sent, but the Json is wrapped inside extra properties.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        // Temporarily using Dynamic 
        dynamic res = new ExpandoObject();

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var status = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        res.status = status.ToString();

        return new JsonResult{Data = res};
    }
```

Which returns cookies but wrapped Json:

```
 {"contentEncoding":null,"contentType":null,"data":{"status":"Success"},"jsonRequestBehavior":1,"maxJsonLength":null,"recursionLimit":null}
```

Now I am guessing that his is happening because the SignInManager is probably assigning the cookies to HttpContext.Current.Response object, which was generated earlier. And when I return a JsonResult, ASP.NET bolts this result on to the HttpContext.Current.Response and sends to client, therefore having the cookies.

But when I return a HttpResponseMessage, ASP.NET returns the newly created HttpResponse, which does not have the SignInManager cookies. Am I right to think that?

**EDIT 1:** As Suggested by @David Tansey I tried the following, which still does not set cookies but returns correct Json

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {            
        var status = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        return Json(new {status = status.ToString()});
    }
```

Returns correct json, but no cookies:

```
{"status":"Success"}
```

**FIX:** After @David Tansey pointed out using an anonymous type new { }, i decided to try it out. And the following two methods work

**MVC**

had to return a ActionResult/JsonResult, for which all fields apart from Data were null, and had to return an `Anonymous` type rather than a dynamic `ExpandoObject()` as the dynamic object was causing the serializer to bloat the returned Json

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [NgValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        var status = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        //return Json(new {status = status.ToString()});
        // OR
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status.ToString() } };
    }
```

**WebApi 2**

Had to change the return type to object, which in gets serialized to Json, and also sets cookies. Returning a HttpResponseMessage causes the cookies that SignInManager set to get lost I guess as its start using the newly returned response object.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [NgValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<object> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        var status = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        return new {status = status.ToString()};
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about. Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Added Sample Code, basically using MVC.ActionResult = Cookies but Wrapped JSON, but WebApi.HttpResponseMessage = No Cookies but correct JSON

Comment: If you do not like what `JsonResult()` wraps around your data, why not just use the `Json(object)` method instead?  Something like, `return Json( new { status = res });`

Comment: @DavidTansey see Edit 1, returns correct Json, but still no cookies :-(

Comment: My suggestion was attempting to address the part of your question where you say: _'all was fine using MVC 5. But for the life of me, I cannot get the standard MVC controller to return just simple JSON_'

Comment: I will try putting that back into MVC controller, see what it returns

Comment: That worked! :|  Add it as an answer, and i will accept

Comment: From looking at Json(object)  it returns JsonResult, do you know why my original JsonResult{Data = res}; was not working and coming back bloated?

Comment: Turns out that JsonResult does not like dynamic objects. Needs it to be an anonymous object :|

Comment: I'm looking at the same MSDN documentation right now, and I'm asking myself the same question.  Very interesting.

Comment: I think dynamic objects internally keep the properties in a dictionary, which in causes the serializer to output an array of KeyValuePairs when using dynamic :|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69533/discussion-between-david-tansey-and-michal-ciechan).

Comment: Although a bit cryptic, this was actually helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, sorry for the crptography!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have set AuthenticationMode as Passive. Try to change this to Active.

**Source** http://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/host-authentication-and-web-api-with-owin-and-active-vs-passive-authentication-middleware/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem may be that you are trying to use cookies, when instead you should be using tokens...and this is why you are running into the hackyness issue.

See this guide to learn how to set up token based auth: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

(Generally I would post the relevant code, but there is quite a bit that goes into setting it up.)